# XML comparison tool

Tags: java, xml

Is there any program/Tool , to compare the individual xmls' or two folders with xml's.

I know I can use Araxis / XMDiff from command line or use scripting to get the report. 
What I'm looking for is to exclude some of the Xpath while comparing , and I want to do this from command line , but not from GUI.

If there is no tool I'll have to write a tool in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Beyond Compare 3 has a CLI - http://www.scootersoftware.com/.

I'm still using version 2, it's the best comparison tool around in my opinion.